# postgresql join query

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I have two tables T1 and T2

```
T1
-id
-columnA
-columnB
-columnC

T2
-id
-columnX
-columnY
-columnZ
```

I have a query like

```
Select t1.* t2.columnZ 
from T1 t1 
  left join on T2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t2.columnZ = 'test'
```

I want result like if "where t2.columnZ = 'test'" does not return any row then it should return value of columnZ as null value

Comment: can you explain what the output you required ?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT    t1.*
,         t2.columnZ
FROM      T1 t1
LEFT JOIN T2 t2 
       ON t1.id = t2.id
      AND t2.columnZ = 'test'
```

You also missed a comma, and you had a misplaced `on`.

Comment: @wingedpanther, I replaced the original `where` with `and`, with `where` selects only those that have 'test'. The question, as I understood it, is to get a complete set, some may have 'test' others not. I also don't get your edit, what was the point?